# What is an effective way to test if a user has permissions to some files?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, permissions, directory

Visual Studio c# Xml File Permissions

I need to find a way to determine if a user have permissons to access a document from either a url or a local directory. How would I go about checking their permissions IE what method would I use? If it helps or makes a difference what so ever I am pulling the addresses out of an XML file as a string and running each individual node pertaining to location.

Edit: The goal is to Filter the Xml file to display if the user has access to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and most effective way is to simply try to access the file. If the user doesn't have permission you'll get an exception (UnauthorizedAccessException).

Trap that (and any other specific exception that could be raised) and display a suitable error message.

Comment: My goal here is to filter the XML file, in other words I dont want to have any errors thrown. If user has access display otherwise ignore it.

Comment: @Christoper - in that case just swallow the exception, which is OK as you are catching the *specific* case of unauthorised access.

Comment: Ok which method would you suggest? just use file system?

Comment: @Christopher - Yes. I can't think of anything else that would do the job as easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have used FileInfo in the past and it was quite useful.

see [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx) on exceptions it throws